# SQL Query that shows new starts within the last 30 days and the next 30 days

Tags: sql, oracle

Creating a report in Oracle OTBI to show any new starts within the last month days or the next month.

Currently I have an SQL query that shows the new starts within the last month days but unsure how to make it so that it also includes those that start within the next month.

```
SELECT "Person Names"."Full Name" saw_0,
       "Worker"."Person Start Date" saw_1,
       "Worker"."Termination Date" saw_2,
       "Manager"."Business Unit" saw_3
  FROM "Workforce Management - Person Real Time"
 WHERE ("Manager"."Business Unit" = ' ')
   AND ("Worker"."Person Start Date" >= (TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_MONTH, -1, CURRENT_DATE)))
```

Comment: First question: Do you want to check last 30 days and next 30 days or do you want to check date - one month or date + one month? This is not the same. Second question: Should the time be considered or ignored when comparing?

Comment: Would like to check the last 30 days and the next 30 days. Time can be ignored

Comment: See answer below

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try this

```
SELECT    
"Person Names"."Full Name" saw_0,    
"Worker"."Person Start Date" saw_1,    
"Worker"."Termination Date" saw_2,    
"Manager"."Business Unit" saw_3    
FROM "Workforce Management - Person Real Time"    
where "Manager"."Business Unit" = ' '    
and "Worker"."Person Start Date" between sysdate -30 and sysdate +30
```

Comment: Have tried to use this but it returns an error

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE employees (employee_id, first_name, last_name, hire_date) AS
SELECT 1,  'Alice', 'Abbot', DATE '2022-04-03'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Beryl', 'Baron',DATE '2022-05-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Carol', 'Chase',DATE '2022-05-18' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Debra', 'Doris', DATE '2022-05-28' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Emily', 'Evans',DATE '2022-06-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'Fiona', 'Frank',DATE '2022-06-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'Gemma', 'Grace', DATE '2022-06-30' FROM DUAL;

SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE 
hire_date BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE)-30
AND
TRUNC(SYSDATE)+ 30;


EMPLOYEE_ID    FIRST_NAME    LAST_NAME    HIRE_DATE
2    Beryl    Baron    01-MAY-22
3    Carol    Chase    18-MAY-22
4    Debra    Doris    28-MAY-22
6    Fiona    Frank    11-JUN-22
```

Comment: Hi, Have created the following SQL code but it does not seem to be working.                           SELECT DISTINCT

"Person Names"."Full Name" saw_0,

"Worker"."Person Start Date" saw_1,

"Worker"."Termination Date" saw_2,

"Manager"."Business Unit" saw_3

FROM "Workforce Management - Person Real Time"

WHERE

("Manager"."Business Unit" = 'Solutions (UK)') AND ("Worker"."Person Start Date" BETWEEN (TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_MONTH, -1, CURRENT_DATE)) AND (TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_MONTH, 1, CURRENT_DATE))

Comment: If you are looking for more help it would be in your best interest to provide create table statements for each table populated with data (like I did in my sample) along with a minimal expected output. Since your responding to my post I suspect my solution didn't answer your question. Since nobody can read minds people aren't going to guess what you want. Create a test case so myself or others can aid you